Viewing a PDF that Stored in a Private Cloud Storage Bucket
Background: I am working on a generative AI app, where basically a user uploads a document to cloud storage (through a service account), and once that document arrives in cloud storage, it's taken and evaluated through Document AI, generating some data I want to display to the user. After it's done being evaluated, that data is then stored in firestore, including the cloud storage url of the document that was analyzed. On the front end, the user can see a list of all their analyzed documents.
Here-in lies the issue: When a user clicks on one of the items in this list to view their analysis, it shows the analyzed data in a digestible format, as well as a preview of the document they uploaded. Currently, I can show the analyzed data no issue, but I'm having trouble displaying a preview of the analyzed document. This document will be a PDF or some form of image, so I've decided to use react-pdf to render the pdf on the front end. However, when trying to render the PDF, I keep running into a CORS-policy issue, specifically No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. This is what my cors-policy looks like that I've set on my storage bucket:
[{"origin": ["http://localhost:3500/"],"responseHeader": ["Content-Type","Cache-Control"],"method": ["GET", "HEAD","OPTIONS"]}]
For further reference, this is what my react-pdf component looks like:
<Document
    file={*PDF URL HERE* || ''}
    options={{
      withCredentials: true,
      httpHeaders: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, HEAD',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
      }
    }}
    loading={
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }}
      >
        <CircularProgress />
      </Box>
    }
    error={'Failed to load PDF preview'}
  >
    <Page
      pageNumber={1}
      height={300}
    />
  </Document>

Even after setting the cors policy, I continue to run into the same error. I am trying to keep my bucket private, however even if it was public, I feel like I'd run into this same issue anyways. I also don't want to use an iframe, as I want to try understanding CORS-policy a bit better, and an iframe is harder to style

I actually just needed to generate a url whenever someone clicks on one of the items on the front end. I generated this url by having the document's name and the bucket it was stored in saved within the item, and when the item is clicked, the document name and bucket are sent to an api route to generate the url. Below is the code:
Front-End:
const generateUrl = useCallback(async (item) => {
    try {
      const payload = JSON.stringify({
        doc_name: item?.cloud_storage_id,
        bucket: item?.bucket
      })

      const res = await fetch(`/api/storage/${payload}`)

      if (!res.ok) {
        const data = await res.json()
        throw new Error(`${res.status} - ${res.statusText} - ${data.error}`)
      }

      const generatedUrl = await res.json()
      setGeneratedUrl(generatedUrl)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`There was an error generating the url to view the analyzed document: ${error}`)
      openSnackbar({ message: 'There was an error previewing your analyzed document, please try again later', severity: 'error' })
    }
  })

API Route:
import { storage } from "@/lib/storage";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { query: { payload } } = req
  const { doc_name, bucket } = JSON.parse(payload)
  const token = await getToken({ req })

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'User access denied' })
  }

  try {
    const options = {
      version: 'v4',
      action: 'read',
      expires: Date.now() + 3600 * 1000
    }

    //await needs to be here, even though VS code says it does not
    const [signedUrl] = await storage.bucket(bucket).file(doc_name).getSignedUrl(options)

    return res.status(200).json(signedUrl)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error generating signed url for document with doc_name: ${doc_name}: ${error}`)
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' })
  }
}

I then just set the returned url to a state and it worked perfectly

In your case, you want to give access to the bucket directly from the browser.
First of all, if you do that with a private bucket, it won't work because the browser can't add the correct credential to the Cloud Storage API (access token).
The solution would be to set the bucket public and configure CORS
But, because it's documents uploaded by users, maybe confidential or sensitive, public bucket is not an option.
Here the solution would be to propose a signed URL to allow the browser to download the file. Because it's a GET on an URL, the CORS should not be a problem (CORS are preflight request on PUT, POST, PATH and DELETE verbs. Normally GET is not concerned but I'm not a frontend expert).
Then, because you have the file downloaded on the browser, the react code should be able to display it.

Another option would be to use the backend to serve the PDF. I do not like this option, especially if the PDF is large because it will slow your backend (saturation) and will cost more in egress.

The correct option, would be to a combination of 2: generate thumbnail/overview on server side and serve them from your backend. To download the whole PDF, use the signed URL

So are you saying that I should generate the signed url, and save that with the firestore data, when the evaluated data is being saved on the server side?

No, the signedURL has a limited life duration. You have to store the real GCS path in firestore, and generate a signedURL when the user want to download the document

Okay, I think I understand. Sanity check for how I think I should do it, but in the web app, the user can very easily and quickly switch between their different analysis, so my thinking is I store information necessary to generate the signed url in the firestore document, and when the user clicks on the item in the front end, it'll generate that signed url. Does that make sense/ do you think that might work?

Yes, when it click, you can generate the signed URL and send a redirect with the signed URL to allow the user downloading it.
